# How can I draw the link between negation inconsistency and this result?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

If Γ ⊢ ∃x∃y (φ(x)∧φ(y)∧x≠y) , how does adding ∀x(x=c↔φ(x)) result in an inconsistent set?

I know that inconsistent has two variants, namely negation inconsistency and absolute inconsistency? How can I prove the former?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The first formula asserts that there are two different objects that are $\varphi$.

The first formula implies that every object that is $\varphi$ is equal to $c$.

From the first one, by Existential instantiation,we get: $\varphi(c_1)$ and $\varphi(c_2)$, with $\lnot (c_1 = c_2)$.

Using the second one, by Universal instantiation, we get: $c_1=c$ and $c_2=c$, from which [transitivity of equality] we have: $c_1=c_2$, and thus the contradiction.